# How to load test search options in a website?

Tags: load-testing

When 100 users search for a content called "maths" through google search now i want to put load test through "Jmeter".

I want to know whether i have to make Parameter for this type of load test?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by creating test plan as below,

- Add a Http sampler with  **CSV DATA SET CONFIG** (element that allows
  you to read different parameters from text file for
  parameterization) and configure text file data to a **PARAMETER_VARIABLE** ( **[Read this blazemeter blog for better understanding](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)** ).
- Use **https:// www.google.com/search?q=${PARAMETER_VARIABLE}** URL
  in Http Sampler.
- Set Number of threads to 100

**NOTE**: You are not suppose to do Google search load testing; it may illegal and try to find answer by googling before posting the question.